# Lifecycle of a Java class in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

Like the lifecycle of UI controllers in android studio, I want to know if there is any lifecycle-like concept for java classes in android studio?

Taking the example of `onCreate` method of the activity below:-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // The activity is being created.
}
```

So the question is, if Java classes also have any states like this?

Comment: Life cycle of a class is as you defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java classes don't really have a lifecycle.  They're constructed when you call the constructor, they last until the garbage collector says they can be deleted, and then the memory is freed.  There is a finalizer that's called right before that happens, but using it is discouraged without a real need-  it slows the garbage collector down significantly.

The onCreate of Activity works just like a normal function does.  Its being called by the class that created the instance of the Activity.  This class is part of the Android framework, but is just another normal Java class.  It basically goes:

```
MyActivity activity = new MyActivity();
activity.onCreate(bundle);
//Does some other stuff
oldActivity.onPause()
activity.onStart()
activity.onResume()
oldActivity.onStop()
```

You can apply the same discipline to objects if you have a need, but its not built in for anything.  Not even Activity-  its just the framework class that launches activities handling this kind of behavior.

Comment: Meaning everything is being managed by the garbage collection.

Comment: @AnkitKumarMaurya  Not really.  GC manages deletion.  It doesn't manage creation.  And it doesn't really get to decide when to delete things.  It can only delete things that are no longer in use.  It just gets to decide what to delete when the JRE tells it to check if it can free up memory.  It doesn't even get to decide when to free up memory (the JRE does that).